# How to covert JSON data(in PHP variable) into Jquery array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I tried to get addresses by giving the postcode of it and used getaddress.io site api with php and it gave the JSON result set like given below and the issue is the result set in a php variable *$file*. now i have to **covert JSON result into jquery array**.

```
{
"Latitude":-0.020223,
"Longitude":51.504859,
"Addresses":[
  "Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Coutts & Co, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Diligence Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doctors of the World UK, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doyle Clayton, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  ]
}
```

Output i wanted as a jquery array values is,

`var output= [
  "Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Coutts & Co, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Diligence Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doctors of the World UK, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doyle Clayton, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  ];`

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you generating javascript on the fly with php code? http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Surely `var output = data.Addresses` ?

Comment: could you show me example?

Comment: wherever you are making the ajax call, you must be having the callback function, so in that callback.. function(response){ var output = response.Addresses; }

Comment: var data = <?php echo $file ;?> ; it showing nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Darren comment above:

```js
var data = {
"Latitude":-0.020223,
"Longitude":51.504859,
"Addresses":[
  "Abbey Offices Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Coutts & Co, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Diligence Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doctors of the World UK, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  "Doyle Clayton, 1 Canada Square, LONDON",
  ]
};
  
var output = data.Addresses;
alert(output);
```

Comment: And the winner is dave! Unless the OP can actually generate the json string via php code that he wanted to modify?